# Is it possible to run a free version of sql server 2008 to the foundation Server 2008 Server

Tags: database

I'm planning to run a ms sql server 2008r2 express edition on a windows server 2008R2 foundation edition. Is it possible? what are the possible issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can install SQL Server on 2008 R2 Foundation but you have to consider some drawbacks due to Foundation edition limitations. Please note that Foundation is limited to one CPU socket support, 8 GB ram maximum and you have a limit on network connections. Nowadays a single socket will support many CPU cores, so processing power may not be a problem, but the limited number of connections and the small amount of ram supported can be. It depends on how much work your databases will do and how they will be optimized. Because of Foundation is a so limited edition, I would not recommend to install SQL server on it for other that very small and low profile databases.